# Modifying matrix by column in R

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I'm trying to move to R and I'd like your help for missing some basic thing with how R manipulates matrices. I have a large term-document matrix and I would like to test different term weight methods. But I can't obtain a basic operation to function correctly. When I make a term-document matrix (terms in rows) it works, but my data is in the document-term format (documents in rows). I don't understand what's going on. I'm showing an example below:

Term-document data in td_in.csv:

```
1,1,1
2,2,2
2,2,0
2,0,0
0,1,2
0,1,2
```

Document-term data in dt_in.csv:

```
1,2,2,2,0,0
1,2,2,0,1,1
1,2,0,0,2,2
```

It's **the same** data of fake term frequencies.

For example I want to compute term probabilities. First term-document way:

```
  #td_in.csv is 1,1,1\n2,2,2\n2,2,0\n2,0,0\n0,1,2\n0,1,2
  td<-read.csv("td_in.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
  tdm=as.matrix(td)
  rsms=rowSums(tdm)
  tp_td=td/rsms
  tp_td
```

Correct:

```
V1        V2        V3
1 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
2 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
3 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000
4 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
5 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667
6 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667
```

Then document-term way:

```
  #dt_in.csv is 1,2,2,2,0,0\n1,2,2,0,1,1\n1,2,0,0,2,2
  dt<-read.csv("dt_in.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
  dtm=as.matrix(dt)
  csms=colSums(dtm)
  tp_dt=dtm/csms
  tp_dt
```

This is what's produced:

```
V1        V2        V3 V4        V5        V6
[1,] 0.3333333 1.0000000 0.6666667  1 0.0000000 0.0000000
[2,] 0.1666667 0.6666667 0.3333333  0 0.1666667 0.3333333
[3,] 0.2500000 0.6666667 0.0000000  0 0.5000000 0.6666667
```

Why is the document-term version not working? I know that I can transpose the matrix, then do the calculation, and then transpose it back, but I would like to know how to manipulate the matrix column way too. Could someone explain what am I doing incorrectly? Thank you! Adam

Comment: Thank you! I just have read it. So the matrix must be transposed first? I wanted to avoid this because it's a huge file. I think it will run out of memory.

Comment: OK: I now see that these are alternatives. I will test which will not result in out of memory. Thank you again!

Comment: Zheyuan: `sweep` is perfect! I tried so far only on a part of the big matrix and it's faster than the transpose. How can I "thumbs-up your answer" on the forum?